# Last Modified date of a file- write to a text file

Tags: vbscript

This script works fine ( even though 20 + forums all said it couldn't be done, so perhaps it will help others.

It checks for the newest file in the folder and gives me the date in a pop up window.

I would like it to check the file and save it into a .txt file

```
`Option Explicit  
Dim fso, path, file, recentDate, recentFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set recentFile = Nothing
For Each file in fso.GetFolder("c:\check").Files
If (recentFile is Nothing) Then
Set recentFile = file
ElseIf (file.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified) Then
Set recentFile = file
End If
Next

If recentFile is Nothing Then
WScript.Echo "No report has been run before"
Else
WScript.Echo "This report was last run at "  & " " & 
recentFile.DateLastModified
End If
```

it is saved as .vbs

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, files are in .vbs and you want to save them as .txt. Here's how to do it.

I don't know want you mean by check though.

```
Option Explicit 

Dim fso, path, file, recentDate, recentFile

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set recentFile = Nothing

For Each file in fso.GetFolder("c:\check").Files

    If (recentFile is Nothing) Then
        Set recentFile = file
    ElseIf (file.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified) Then
        Set recentFile = file
    End If

    'replace extension in full path - not case sensitive
    file_name_txt = Replace(File.Path, ".vbs", ".txt", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)

    'Warning - moving the file will delete the source
    file.move file_name_txt

    'You may also use file.copy to keep the original
    'file.copy file_name_txt, True '(overwrite)

Next

If recentFile is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo "No report has been run before"
Else
    WScript.Echo "This report was last run at " & recentFile.DateLastModified
End If
```